# Write out file names and its contents from a folder to a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, text

I want to write the filename and its content to a dataframe. The data basically contains the figure and its captions info from articles. Eg) *2_1.jpg* is a figure and *2_1.txt* is the corresponding caption captured in Page 2 of the article. The folder structure looks like below,

```
Documents
  -Article1
      -2_1.jpg
      -2_1.txt
      -3_1.jpg
      -3_1.txt
      -3_2.jpg
      -3_2.txt
  -Article2
      -2_1.jpg
      -2_1.txt
      -2_2.jpg
      -2_2.txt
      -3_2.jpg
      -3_2.txt
```

I used dictionary to store the data as key(filename)-value(contents) pairs, but all the file names and its content are not stored because some of the filenames are repeated (Like *2_1.txt* is present in both Article1 and Article2, however the contents will be different). I used below code to create the dataframe, but couldn't retain all filenames since duplicates are not allowed in dict.

```
# Create Dictionary for File Name and Text
file_name_and_text = {}
for path,dirs,files in os.walk('C:/Users/Project/Documents/'):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.txt'):
            fullname = os.path.join(path,file)
            with open(fullname, "r") as target_file:
                file_name_and_text[file] = target_file.read()
df = (pd.DataFrame.from_dict(file_name_and_text, orient='index')
             .reset_index().rename(index = str, columns = {'index': 'image_path', 0: 'text'}))
df['image_path'] = df['image_path'].str.replace('.txt', '.jpg', regex = True)
df.head()

Output:

  image_path    text
0   2_1.jpg ['Figure 1.Embedded trials of the...']
1   2_2.jpg [Figure 2. A) Helical wheel projections of zp1â...]
2   3_1.jpg ['Fig. 1. Positions of MHC side chain Trp167 a...]
3   3_2.jpg [Figure 2. A) CD spectra of zp3 in 50 % TFE wit...]
```

How can I retain all image file names and it's corresponding text content. Eg) I want to retain *2_1.jpg* under Article1 as well as *2_1.jpg* under Article2 with their respective contents.

```
Expected Output

      image_path    text
    0   2_1.jpg ['Figure 1.Embedded trials of the...']
    1   3_1.jpg ['Fig. 1. Positions of MHC side chain Trp167 a...]
    2   3_2.jpg [Figure 2. A) CD spectra of zp3 in 50 % TFE wit...]
    3   2_1.jpg [Figure 1. zp3 may lead to the pore formation....]
    4   2_2.jpg [Figure 2. A) Helical wheel projections of zp1â...]
    5   3_2.jpg [Figure 2. Close-up views of A) STEM...]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is suitable to use a full path or just add a prefix path, maybe you can change the code:

```
file_name_and_text[file] = target_file.read()
->
file_name_and_text[fullname] = target_file.read()

or
->
file_name_and_text[path.split('//')[-1] + file] = target_file.read()
```